# NIntegrate::inumr: error

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I'm new to Mathematica and I keep getting this error(in the title) when I'm trying to solve this definite integral numerically.  This is for a math class where we have to use the arc length.

```
f[x_] := 6 x[1 - x]
NIntegrate[Sqrt[1. + f'[x]^2], {x, 0., 1.}]
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I've googled several times and while a lot of people are getting the same error, their solutions/problems aren't really the same as mine.  My instructor showed us this exact syntax I am pretty sure and he was getting the correct answer.

The error is

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Sqrt[1. +36 (1[1+Times[<<2>>]]-(x^[Prime])[Plus[<<2>>]])^2] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,1.}}.

EDIT:  Thank you.  I thought it was brackets for some reason.

Comment: Try `f[x_] := 6 x(1 - x)`: Parentheses for grouping, square brackets for function calls.

Comment: Zach, if you forget your password, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery. If not, then there some other person trying to edit your post and pretend to be you.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_] := 6 x[1 - x]
```

This is a mistake!

The right definition of a function is:

```
f[x_]:=6x(1-x)
```

Please  remember: [] is a function flag. () is grouping the terms of a expression.

Comment: Pretty much what I said in my comment!